# Unable to remove org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryThreadLocal error in web container(tomcat) while using apapche ignite

Tags: multithreading, containers, local, ignite

We are using apache ignite for one of our caching solution,It is perfectly working fine.But while stopping the web container lots of error related to removal of ignite Thread Local is displaying the server log.Since we are not creating any ThreadLocal in our application,how can i remove those Thread local when stopping the server. Some of the errors are mentioned below.

**SEVERE: The web application [/webapp-name] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryThreadLocalContext$1] (value [org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryThreadLocalContext$1@5826d221]) and a value of type [org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryThreadLocalContext] (value [org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryThreadLocalContext@47a32716]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Apr 08, 2021 10:39:34 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/webapp-name] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@63b81d02]) and a value of type [org.apache.ignite.internal.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedObjectStreamRegistry.StreamHolder] (value [org.apache.ignite.internal.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedObjectStreamRegistry$StreamHolder@58474af2]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Apr 08, 2021 10:39:34 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/webapp-name] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal.SuppliedThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal$SuppliedThreadLocal@67782fee]) and a value of type [org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryContextHolder] (value [org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryContextHolder@482bfe01]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.**

Comment: I can see the following ticket:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-967 - maybe you need to reopen it with this message. What is ignite version, by the way?

Comment: Thanks for your reply..We are using ignite 2.8.1 version

Comment: I suggest filing a ticket against Apache Ignite JIRA after checking that the same issue is present in 2.10.0.

Comment: I have tested client using ignite-core-2.10.0.jar,Still the same errors are throwing in server log .We are using version 2.8.1 in server. Do i want change server version also to 2.10?

Comment: What kind of client are you using? Is it a thin client? Please mention it in a ticket if you are going to file.

Comment: Yes java thin client

Comment: You can track this ticket: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-14548